# Querying Django Postgres for Fuzzy FTS + Typeahead

Tags: django, postgresql, full-text-search, typeahead.js

I'm using PostgreSQL 12.3 with Django 3.0.8. I'm trying to implement a typeahead functionality. I tried using Trigram similarity, but that didn't work too well since, if I were to have a text saying "chair," I would have to type "cha" before I get results.

I'm using corejavascript/twitter's typeahead JS library. Their [first example](https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/) (The Basics) allows you to type in a single letter and get results instantly, some of which are not even the prefix of the word.

How would I do that? You can view my current functionality here: https://github.com/Donate-Anything/Donate-Anything/blob/76348e9362d386d3d6375b9a75d47d5765960992/donate_anything/item/views.py#L21-L30

I thought that I should use to_tsvector with a SearchVectorField, but when I implemented that (with a query like this:

```
queryset = (
        Item.objects.defer("is_appropriate")
        .filter(name_search=str(query))
    )
```

then I don't even see the results until I type in the full word. What would my implementation look like then? ([Article for implementing the triggers for SearchVectorField](https://findwork.dev/blog/optimizing-postgres-full-text-search-in-django/))

Comment: The typeahead library that you posted seems to just be performing a case-insensitive match anywhere in the field, to get the same result in Django you can use the standard filters. Is there a reason you are using full text search?

Comment: Hi @IainShelvington I'm using FTS functionality because of performance (and to make sure similar results like "pant" and "pants" aren't duplicated using Trigram). I thought using FTS would help speed up the query, allow for word fuzzy matching and/or prefix matching.

Comment: To replicate the functionality of the library you posted you should be able to just use `.filter(name__icontains=str(query))`

Comment: Yes, I tried that before (maybe a minute before you commented again), and it indeed works, but I was looking for TSVector being of any use performance wise. I guess I'll have to live and learn first. Thank you, though!

Comment: Also, with that query (icontains), would it be wise to add a GIN index?

Comment: If your dataset is small, like 50 entries, performance should be fine.  If your data set is large, I think single-character suggestions based on the dataset of possible results will be pretty useless regardless of performance.  Who is going to search for "red cross" by typing "o"?

Comment: For sure. I did some tests with the English dictionary as a dataset. Seems fine without the index, too, at least for 2 and 4 char suggestions.